# make asynchronous xml request from firefox addon

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

i'm trying to implement xml request in firefox extension when i tried to do that xmlrequest is not defined. i can make call from contentscript but i'm not able to make it from main.js

i tried `Request(options)`

```
var Request = require("sdk/request").Request;
var httpRequest = Request({
  url: "https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=mozhacks&count=1",
  onComplete: function (response) {
    var tweet = response.json[0];

  }
});
```

it is working

but what i need is i want to make asynchronous request

Comment: The code above already is asynchronous.

Comment: @willlma when i used it to call one more xmlrequest that is not working properly.

Comment: You called `httpRequest.get()` twice? If you're redefining `httpRequest` the second time, then it will overwrite your `onComplete`.

Comment: sorry., i'm talking about the request. the answer i got here is working k. @willlma thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to incude `const {Cc, Ci} = require("chrome");`in main.js and

```
var httprequest=Cc["@mozilla.org/xmlextras/xmlhttprequest;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsIXMLHttpRequest);
```